# Chrome developer tool warning on images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.net MVC page is giving Mime type warnings for image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925888/asp-net-mvc-page-is-giving-mime-type-warnings-for-image-files)

I am working in my ASP.NET MVC app within VS 2010 and so I use the development server for this purpose.

When I enable resource traking on Chrome Developer tool I am seeing a plethora of warnings regarding the images of my app. The warning says:

```
Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream.
```

for every image used in my site.

What this warning means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925888](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925888). This is typical of the built in VS web server. I would ignore it or run your site under your local IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your server is sending the wrong `Content-Type` header for the images. You'll want to look at the server configuration to ensure that it's sending images with their correct MIME types (e.g., `image/jpeg` for JPGs, `image/png` for PNGs). Not really a problem just for a dev box, but you wouldn't want your publicly-facing server to do that.

Comment: As I am using the included development server, is this a known behaviour of this? I dont think I can configure it...

Comment: @Lorenzo: Sorry, I've never used the built-in server in VS.Net 2010. I'm surprised it's getting it wrong, frankly. It's presumably getting the MIME type information from Windows, so I'd probably start by looking to see what Windows thinks the MIME types are. Or not worrying about it, frankly.